# Connecting an access point directly to another access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

Can I connect another access point via ethernet port, to an access point which is connected to my router?

Simply put, Access Point A is connected to my main router. And I want to connect another access point- Access point B directly to the ethernet port of Access Point A, rather than connecting all the way to the main router. I need to do this as the main router is way far from Access Point B's location.

Is this possible? Would there be any conflict with IP address? Or would I need a switch?

Comment: That depends entirely on the AP and how it is configured... But in general, yes it should work as long as you have supply power the second AP (POE will not pass through the first AP) as the second ethernet port in most AP's by default is just a passthough of default VLAN.